# Issue with SortFields function and ranges

Tags: excel, vba

My problem with the code below is that because of the `select` of the range that I have defined I can't run this code successfully while on another Sheet. I know that it's bad practice to use `.select` and now I know why, it causes so many problems. I'm not sure how to fix this code so that it'll work properly.

```
Sub Sorting(sorted As Range, keys As Range)


'Range("A1:A4").Select
sorted.Select
Sheets("IDBHour1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
Sheets("IDBHour1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=keys, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
       Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With Sheets("IDBHour1").Sort
    .SetRange sorted
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select in order to sort.  How are you passing the ranges in the calling procedure?

My personal preference would be to pass the ranges as strings and then make them into ranges inside the sub. That code runs from anywhere. The IDBHour1 sheet needs neither selection nor activation.

```
Sub Sorting(sortSheet As String, sorted As String, keys As String)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sortRange As Range
Dim sortKeys As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sortSheet)
Set sortRange = ws.Range(sorted)
Set sortKeys = ws.Range(keys)

ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sortKeys, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
       Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange sortRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub

Sub testSort()
    Call Sorting("IDBHour1", "A1:A10", "A1")
End Sub
```